# how have sum for each columns for selected rows?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to make a table to be able to help me make price comparisons.
Explanations:
In my table I have:

- Project
- Product
- Manufacturer
- Title
- Quantity
- Unit buying price (sum)
- Total price buying (sum)
- Multiply (average)
- Unit sales price (sum)
- Total sales price (sum)
- Profit (sum)

The ideal in my case would be to select the lines I want to keep to see the total price of my choices. So I can see the cost of different options.

someone would have an idea or have already encountered this problem?

Thank you for helps :)

**EDIT** the sum for each columns work fine, but when i don't find how to have only the sum for each columns when i select them.
Sorry but i am not comfortable with js :-/

```js
// Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
var intVal = function ( i ) {
    return typeof i === 'string' ?
    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
    typeof i === 'number' ?
    i : 0;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [{
          targets: [4,5,6,8,9,10],
          render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2)
        }],
        responsive: true,
        paging:false,
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
            var sumColumns = [4,5,6,8,9,10];

            sumColumns.forEach(function(colIndex){
            // Total over all pages
                var total = api
                    .rows({ selected: true })
                    .column(colIndex)
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Total over this page
                var pageTotal = api
                    .column(colIndex, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Update footer
                $( api.columns(colIndex).footer() ).html(
                    total
                );
            }) 
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="page">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap table1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>projectid</th>
            <th>productid</th>
            <th>manufacturerid</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>PAU a</th>
            <th>PAT a</th>
            <th>Coef a</th>
            <th>PVU a</th>
            <th>PVT a</th>
            <th>Profit a</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>130</td>
            <td>1300</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>260</td>
            <td>2600</td>
            <td>1300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>PAU a</th>
            <th>PAT a</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>PVU a</th>
            <th>PVT a</th>
            <th>Profit a</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We normally expect that you have something to show that you tried already, or that you at least ask _specific_ questions about a certain aspect of the problem. Please edit your question and add anything you already have to show in that regard.

Comment: I have edit my post. Sorry it wasn't very clear, i hope it is now :) Thanks

Comment: @richard03 did you attend to answers?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to calculate your columns and the average for the 7th column,
this is separate from your code, you can use it anywhere that you want.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var sumColumns = [4,5,6,8,9,10];
        $.each(sumColumns, function(index, val) {
            var total = 0;
         jQuery('tbody tr td:nth-child('+val+')').each(function(index, el) {
                total += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
            jQuery('tfoot tr th:nth-child('+val+')').each(function(index, el) {
                $(this).html(total);
            });
        });
        var total = 0;
        jQuery('tbody tr td:nth-child(7)').each(function(index, el) {
                total += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
            jQuery('tfoot tr th:nth-child(7)').each(function(index, el) {
                $(this).html(total/jQuery('tbody tr td:nth-child(7)').length);
            });
    });
```